# django view to retrieve data from db based on number or current date

Tags: python, database, django, view, django-queryset

I am trying to develop a webpage that will visualize content based on the date. It will be used for planning purposes our soccer club. Every Saturday and Sunday the website should show the dressing rooms and the teams that will use it.

I new to OOP and django and I would appreciate it if you could help me out.

I have made the following model in models.py

```
from django.db import models

class KleedkamerIndeling(models.Model):
    kleedkamer_1 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    kleedkamer_2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    kleedkamer_3 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    kleedkamer_4 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    kleedkamer_5 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    kleedkamer_6 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True) 
    kleedkamer_7 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True) 
    kleedkamer_8 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    speel_ronde = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    indelings_datum = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.speel_ronde
```

I managed to register the model in the admim section of the website and I am able to add entries to the database.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from.models import KleedkamerIndeling

class KleedkamerIndelingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = KleedkamerIndeling

admin.site.register(KleedkamerIndeling,KleedkamerIndelingAdmin)
```

It is now time to create my view. I want to retrieve data from the databse depending on the date which is stored to 'indelings_datum'. However, because this is a date I decided to start with retreive the data based on the 'speel_ronde' and advance from there.

I currently made the following view, by combining stuff from all the django books and tutorials I have done. Neglect the current_time view that was just something I tried separately (worked).

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.dates import TodayArchiveView
from models import KleedkamerIndeling
import datetime


def current_time(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>Het is nu %s</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)

def vandaag(request):
    queryset = KleedkamerIndeling.objects.all().filter(speel_ronde=25)
    kleedkamer1 = queryset.kleedkamer_1
    html = "<html><body>Room 1 will be used by %s</body></html>" % kleedkamer1
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

I get an error when I access the url to links to the view. I says 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'kleedkamer_1'. However, if I access the database via the admin then I can see all the example data I have put in.

After this works I want to retrieve only the data that belongs the a specific data..

Yes I know that I need to put the html (and css) in a different way. I already managed to do that but I now what to focus on the core functionality first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.objects.filter()` returns a QuerySet. If you are sure that a filter returns only one model you can do `KleedkamerIndeling.objects.get(speel_ronde=25)`. Otherwise the QuerySet behaves like a list, that means you can for example take out the first one (`kleedkamer1 = queryset[0].kleedkamer_1`).

Answer (score 0):

Queryset is a list. So you have to take 1st index from that list, like:

```
def vandaag(request):
    queryset = KleedkamerIndeling.objects.all().filter(speel_ronde=25)[0]
```